# adding up return values from function using php

Tags: php

I have a function that returns total points for a player.  That works without issues and returns values correctly.  However, I need to  get values for a whole team.  So I tried numerous things and can't get it to work.

```
$home1points = getplayerpoints($home1g1) + getplayerpoints($home1g2) + getplayerpoint($home1g3) + getplayerpoints($home1g4) +getplayerpoints($home1g5) + getplayerpoints($home1g6)
```

this returns 0000000.

I'm not sure how to add all the function values together, any ideas where I'm wrong?

Comment: What is `getplayerpoints()` returning?

Comment: Adding stuff together, using the `+` operator, **cannot** result in `0000000`. It will either result in a number (an integer or a float), or some kind of error (adding stuff that cannot be added, such as an object or resource). Are you 100% sure this is the code that gives you the output? An answer to @AbraCadaver's question would also be helpful to us.

Comment: The values returned are integers--however I think the issues is cause the values are null until scoring starts they show up as 0

Comment: Okay then. We need to see the code for the `getplayerpoints()` function (and any custom functions that it calls) in order to help you. It is obviously doing something iffy. I am guessing it `echo`s something; that would explain the string of zeros that you are getting.

Comment: Yes. It echoes out the value. So I just assign points to a player and then the function echoes back the value to a spot in the table.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the getplayerpoints() function echo's out an integer. When you are using a function in a context like yours (adding numbers together) the function must RETURN a value not ECHO it.

I think you have something like

```
function getplayerpoints(){
    // Some stuff done here
    echo $points;
}
```

Instead it should be:

```
function getplayerpoints(){
    // Some stuff done here
    return $points;
}
```

Now when you are adding points together every time you call the getplayerpoints() function it doesnt echo but return the number.